# Is there an analogy of quantum mechanical phase symmetry in classical physics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, hilbert-space, symmetry, complex-numbers

In quantum mechanics, phase symmetry is the fact that the state of a system can be multiplied by a length 1 complex number without changing the probabilities of observables.

Is there an analogous symmetry concept in classical physics?

Answer (score 4):

A classical analogue to unitary transformations, which uses the principle of phase indifference with some restrictions (for unitary operators  $\hat{U}^+\hat{U}$ must be equal to $1$), would be orthogonal transformations of real vectors. There's a good text about this in the book [*Student Friendly Quantum Field Theory by Robert D. Klauber*](http://www.quantumfieldtheory.info/).

> A unitary transformation is called unitary because its operation on (transformation of) a state vector leaves
>   the magnitude of the state vector unchanged, i.e., the state vector magnitude is multiplied by unity. It is the
>   complex space analogue of an orthogonal transformation in Cartesian coordinate space, which, when acting on
>   a (real number) vector in that space, rotates the vector but does not stretch or compact it. A unitary
>   transformation can be thought of as "rotating" a (complex number) state vector in Hilbert space (the complex
>   space where each coordinate axis is an eigenvector) without changing the "length" (magnitude) of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

For any wave-like object, one can change the phase without changing the intensity. This holds for instance for for electromagnetic waves, acoustic waves & water waves.

Comment: Changing the phase does change the instantaneous intensity of a wave;  it's only the time-averaged intensity that is unaffected.  Since the instantaneous intensity is something that's classically observable, this isn't really a good analogy.

Comment: I can see your point. Still, for waves with circular polarization, the analogy would be better. This does disqualify acoustic and water waves, but does work for electromagnetic waves an transverse waves in a string. Although of course the phase also remains observable in these latter cases.